# if statement and functions

Tags: php, web

I sometimes see code that looks like this:

```
if(!Somefunction()){
    // ...
}else{
    // ...
}
```

I am more of a java developer and the only way I know the above statement holds is if the function returns a true or false at the end.

Does every function that is used in this format have to return a true or false? Or does this mean if the function is successfully executed?

Comment: It has to return true/false or an expression that evaluates to true or false in php. That is why using triple equals is pretty important

Comment: @Jhecht the specific, undetailed example you give (PHP) may be more confusing than helpful, eg. vaguely hinting at triple equals.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, not necessarily `True` or `False`. In PHP any variable can be converted to [boolean](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php).

When converting to boolean, the following values are considered `False`:

```
the boolean FALSE itself
the integer 0 (zero)
the float 0.0 (zero)
the empty string, and the string "0"
an array with zero elements
an object with zero member variables (PHP 4 only)
the special type NULL (including unset variables)
SimpleXML objects created from empty tags
```